# CSS grid-template-areas issues

Tags: html, css, layout

I am very new to CSS/HTML and am having issues with getting grid-template-areas to work.

[I'm trying to get the layout to look similar to the Google homepage, but get this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKVLM.png)

The top 2 left buttons correspond to Projects1 and Projects2 in the grid, the top 3 to the right are Resume, square and Contact respectively. The blue logo image is logo in the grid, SB is the search bar.

Any help is appreciated! I had difficulty finding a similar question, but if there is an existing duplicate please let me know.

CSS:

```
.Resume { grid-area: Resume}
.Contact { grid-area: Contact}
.dropdown {grid-area: square}
.logo {grid-area: logo}
.SB {grid-area: Search-Bar}
.Projects {grid-area: Projects}
.Lucky {grid-area: Lucky}

.container {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    " . . . . . Resume square Contact "
    ". . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . logo . . ."
    ". . . . SB  . . ."
    ". . . . Projects1 . Projects2 ."
    ". . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . ."
    ". . . . . . . .";

  }


.Resume a {
  color: black;
  font: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Resume a:hover {
  color: black;
  font: Arial;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  justify-content: left;
}


.Contact button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 134, 248);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Futura;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.SB input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 134, 248);
}

.Projects1 button {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Futura;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: left;
}

.Projects2 button {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border: none;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Futura;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Name</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/HPstylesheet.css">
<style> 
  .search {
    background-image: url(./search.jpg);
    position: left;
    background-size: 25px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class = "container">

    <div class = "Resume">
     <a  href = "www.example.com"> Resume </a>
    </div>


  <div class = "dropdown">
    <span> 
      <img data-toggle="dropdown" src="images/square.jpg">
    </span>


  <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a target="_blank" href="#"> <img src="images/linkedin.jpg", width = "50px", heigth = "50px">
          <p >LinkedIn</p>
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="mailto: #"><img src="images/email.jpg", width = "50px", heigth = "50px">
          <p >Email</p>
        </a>

       
        <a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/github.jpg", width = "50px", heigth = "50px"> 
          <p >Github</p>
        </a>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class = "Contact">
    <button> Contact </button>
  </div>

  <div class = "logo">
    <img src = "images/logo.jpg", height = "200px", width = "500px">
  </div>


 <div class = "SB">
    <form action="http://www.example.com/login.php">
  <input type="text" id = "search" placeholder="Hello... :)">
</form>
  </div>


  <div class = "Projects1">
    <button> Projects </button>
  </div>

<div class = "Projects2">
    <button> I'm Feeling Lucky </button>
  </div>


</div>
    

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide your HTML? It seems to have CSS in the HTML area

Comment: Sorry about that! Updated with HTML